# Qt Resource file utilization

Tags: c++, qt

Here i am describing the problem that i faced with Qt resource .rcc file.

first, When i created the .qrc file in my project it will fit all the resources that is added in the qrc, in to executable binary file.

second, rcc file in Qt used for well and optimize resource utilization and when i create it in my project it is still including all the resources (added in .qrc file) into the executable binary file even rcc file already contains all the resources so, my question is why to use this rcc even if resources are included in executable binary file. Why to include redundancy in project??

it may possible i misinterpret something or i am not aware of some points, please correct me if i wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's too late for answer, but may be helps anybody.

I've expected similar problem, and used next solution:
if you use QtCreator, just wrap your RESOURCES += xxx with config condition in .pro file, like that:

```
!realbuild {
    RESOURCES += xxx.qrc
}
```

and set CONFIG+=realbuild to qmake params. What does it given? You may edit your forms with QtCreator's designer, and use resource directly from editor, but it will not be compiled into your target file, resources must be loaded in run-time using QResource::registerResource(). Use can build resources manually, using direct call to rcc tool, or write a simple script, and call it using QMAKE_POST_LINK variable.

Now question is - how to reload resources in run-time?...

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for [Qt resources](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/resources.html):

- include the `.qrc` in your `.pro` file with

```
 RESOURCES = myapp.qrc
```

- create an external binary resource file with `rcc`, then register it at runtime with

```
QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");
```

Don't do both. i.e. if you previously had the `.qrc` directly included in your `.pro`, and now want to include it dynamically, remove the `RESOURCES` line from the project file and do a clean build. External binary resources are not included in your executable if you don't list them in the `RESOURCES` setting of your project.